# How to create different conditional breakpoints for method entry and exit in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I would like to use conditional breakpoints at the entry and exit of the same method, but with different conditions in eclipse.

But eclipse only offers to create one such breakpoint per method.

I already tried exporting the breakpoint for method entry and changing it to exit and then reimporting the entry breakpoint, but that doesn't work. The breakpoint remains unchanged and no second breakpoint is created.

So is there any way I missed to create those two breakpoints?

I'm unable to use line breakpoints because I'm dealing with libs having no source attached.